Do profits actually decrease during booms?
When output exceeds potential output, and the economy isn't in general equilibrium, the mechanism described that brings markets into equilibrium has to do with the fact that firms are not at a profit maximising level of employment and are producing an output that does not maximise their profits. So they raise prices, which decreases aggregate demand until markets are in general equilibrium again.
But this implies that during booms firms are making less profits than in equilibrium conditions. This seems to go against the basic idea of a boom, that it's a period of prosperity where profits go up
